# Camelot is reading only the first page of the pdf

Tags: python, python-camelot

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf(r"C:\Users\Ayush ShaZz\Desktop\Code_Python\FoodCaloriesList.pdf")
for table in tables:
    print(table.df)
```

Its reading only the first page. Someone please help me out

Answer (score 10):

If you want to read all the pages in a pdf then use:

```
camelot.read_pdf('your.pdf', pages='all')
```

Comment: I should specify, it has to be lowercase, 'All' or 'ALL' will raise an exception

Answer (score 7):

By default Camelot only uses the first page, see here: https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart.html

From the link, you can do multiple pages:

```
camelot.read_pdf('your.pdf', pages='1,2,3')
```

Or, if you want to use them all:

```
camelot.read_pdf('your.pdf',pages=1,4-10,20-end )
```

Comment: tables = camelot.read_pdf(r"C:\Users\Ayush ShaZz\Desktop\Code_Python\FoodCaloriesList.pdf",pages='all',multiple_table='true',flavor='lattice')
for table in tables:
    print(table.df)    I already tried that using this the heading doesn't come in correct format  ................................................. the heading is shifted towards left and the content of the table is perfectly printed .... or i will post it as my next question pls help me out ..

Comment: Btw page indices start from 0 => pages='0,1,2'